# How To Download A Google Code Project From Windows Using Cygwin?

Tags: svn, cygwin

I want to download: https://code.google.com/p/example

According to the docs, I need a subversion control system so I downloaded
svn-load from setup.exe and got this:

```
$ svn-load http://example.googlecode.com/svn/trunk ~/src
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/bin/svn-load", line 43, in <module>
import pysvn
ImportError: No module named pysvn
```

Now I'm stuck. I went to the actual url:
http://example.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/Example.txt

I *think* that that is all of the code. So do I just copy and paste it
somewhere?

Comment: Why don't you just setup subversion and type "svn co http://..." in cmd line?

Comment: Do you have python?  "import pysvn" looks like a python import.

Comment: I do NOT have python. Just downloaded and installed. Same thing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using Cygwin, [these instructions](http://github.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg) worked for me:

```
wget rawgit.com/transcode-open/apt-cyg/master/apt-cyg
install apt-cyg /bin
```

Comment: It seems `svn-load` is missing a dependency in the Cygwin distribution.  In the meantime, `python-pysvn` is available in Ports,  use `svn`, or just download the file from the source browser (select the file, then Show details->View raw file).

Comment: In the search bar of setup.exe,  typed svn and it curiously did not give me the svn command. But I found it and was able to dl. Last but not least though, (although this question is answered, thanks a lot), how do I go about creating and executable so I can use the code through the terminal (cyg-apt)? I really apreciate if someone could link me a tutorial or tell me.

Answer (score 0):

You need SVN to do this

```sh
cygcheck -p svn.exe$ | awk 'END {print $1}' FS=/
```

reveals this

```
subversion
```

so then install as such

```
setup -nqP subversion
```